# Check if a DOMnode exists before calling his member functions

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

While parsing a big HTML file, I get this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null

Problem occurs when my script tries to uses DOMnode member function on a non-existing element in a table.
Here's a small piece of code which demonstrate the problem:

```
<?php
$html = "
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo 0</td>
    <td>Bar 0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo 1</td>
    <td>Bar 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
";

$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Ok
$foo_0 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')[0]->textContent;
$bar_0 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')[1]->textContent;

// Ok
$foo_1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')[2]->textContent;
$bar_1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')[3]->textContent;

// No ok -> How to check if it exists ?
$foo_2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')[4]->textContent;

?>
```

The fatal error occurs when the script tries to access the 4th td element.

Comment: You need to break that line down and check each node before calling a method. You already seem to know how to do that by comparing to null; now you just need to do it.

Comment: Can't you just set the element to a variable and check `if( !is_null($element) )` before using it? Using something like XPath to query the DOM would probably be easier though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jonathan for the solution:

```
if(!is_null($dom->getElementsByTagName('td')[4])){
  $foo_2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')[4]->textContent;
}
```